# Clojure can't find java constructors for native classes?

Tags: java, clojure

I want to make a function that I can pass a map of functions and apply those functions to another map--think of it as coercing a map of strings to arbitrary types. (I'd love to do something higher level like fmap, but one step at a time, right?)

So along the way I figure I will need to do something like

```
user=> (apply Long. "1")
```

But I get this when I try:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Long., compiling:(/private/var/folders/c9/5yl3m9pn0rjdnvqlp5v4fzhr0000gn/T/form-init8437802472507251220.clj:1:1)
```

I can certainly find the class this way:

```
user=> (Long. "1")
1
```

If I do

```
user=> (apply #(Long. %1) "1")
```

I see

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)
```

which is confusing because I just used the constructor. I think I did, anyway. It even finds the right class, just not the constructor of the class.

This also fails, though differently:

```
user=> (apply #(new Long. %1) "1")

CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Long., compiling:(/private/var/folders/c9/5yl3m9pn0rjdnvqlp5v4fzhr0000gn/T/form-init8437802472507251220.clj:1:9)
```

I can get it to not find java.lang.Long, which is interesting:

```
user=> (apply #(new java.lang.Long. %1) "1")

CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Long., compiling:(/private/var/folders/c9/5yl3m9pn0rjdnvqlp5v4fzhr0000gn/T/form-init8437802472507251220.clj:1:9)
```

This works, though:

```
user=> (defn l [x] (Long. x))
#'user/l
user=> (apply l ["1"])
1
```

And I could write my code this way, though it seems a little... off?

Anyway, what's going on here? Why would this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Java functions, including constructors, are not legal Clojure functions and cannot be passed directly to higher-order-functions like `apply` unless they are wrapped inside a Clojure function.

Also, note that `apply` expects an collection of args, as it "unwraps" them from the array.  This works for a vector with one string:

```clojure
(Long. "1")  -> 1
(apply #(Long. %) ["1"] )  -> 1
```

But what you *really* probably want is `mapv` or `map`:

```clojure
(mapv #(Long. %) ["1" "2" "3"] )  -> [1 2 3]
```

I'll let you figure out whats wrong with these failing cases:

```clojure
; failing cases
; (apply Long. ["1"] )
; (apply #(Long. %) ["1" "2" "3"] )
; (apply #(Long. %) "1" "2" ["3"] )
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Well the first case is pretty straightforward from what you said--passing a Java function to a higher-order function. The second and third cases fail because you're passing the wrong number of parameters to the Long constructor.